# Bedeutung von "eines jeden" und Vergleich mit "jedes"

Tags: meaning, difference

Aus der [Bild-Zeitung](http://www.bild.de/sport/2015/voting/bild-leser-waehlen-neuer-zum-sportler-des-jahres-2015-39169270.bild.html):

> (a) Es ist der größte Traum *eines jeden* Tennis-Spielers.

Kann man auch das Folgende sagen, und würde es einen Unterschied dazwischen geben?

> (b) Es ist der größte Traum *jedes* Tennis-Spielers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ein jeder` ist nur eine andere Form für `jeder` (und auch die gebeugten Varianten), da hast du völlig recht. Das Wichtige ist natürlich die Beugung.

Dein zweites Beispiel ist auch in Ordnung und es gibt keinen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen den beiden. Ist halt nur eine stilistische Sache. In manchen Kontexten, so wie im ersten Satz, passt `ein jeder` besser.

Hier noch ein Beispiel aus [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=Das%20wei%C3%9F%20ein%20jeder)

> Das weiß (ein) jeder

Und [die längere Version](http://www.gedichte-fuer-alle-faelle.de/allegedichte/gedicht_3330.html)

> Das weiß ein jeder, wer's auch sei
>   Gesund und stärkend ist das Ei.