# Genitive possesive of "every person"

Tags: translation, genitive

My sentence is "You have found the dream job of every kid".

Is the correct translation "Du hast den Traumberuf jedes Kindes gefunden?"

Could one also say, "Du hast den Traumberuf der alle Kinder gefunden?"

Google Translate gives neither of these results btw!

Comment: Specifically, GT produces *Sie haben den Traumberuf eines jeden Kindes gefunden.* The *du/Sie* switch is expected but I can't explain the *eines*. I'm pretty sure *der alle Kinder* is wrong because there are two determiners in a row, but then you can say the same about *eines jeden Kindes*. DeepL does give the first option with some coaxing.

Comment: PS. GT does seems to be correct, see [DWDS usage examples](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=untertitel&q=eines%20jeden).

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand this "eines jeden" thing either

Comment: PPS. See [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/jeder#d-1-2-1), where it says *gehoben* in green.

Comment: Your title doesn’t fit the question.

Comment: It of course must be "jedweden Kindes" ;)

Comment: @RDBury "eines jeden Kindes" might be a naturalised hypercorrection: "Jeder" (alone, as in "everyone") in genitive must have a companion article: **NOT** "Es ist die Pflicht jedes, etwas zu tun" **BUT** "Es ist die Pflicht eines jeden,..."

Comment: @tofro: Thanks, that would explain why most of the examples I saw were genitive.  Actually, you _can_ have two determiners in a row in English in the form "many a": "I lay awake many a night thinking about this." It's a somewhat dated phrase now, replaced partially by "a lot of". I don't think it generalizes, so you can't say "every a"; I would call it a fixed phrase. Is it fair to call *eines jeden* the same?

Comment: @RDBury That's hard to say - I'd rather say no. I don't really have an explanation why all other cases of "Jeder" work without an article companion, but genitive needs one.

Comment: The article is just needed if there's no object. "der Traumjob jedes Kindes" is genitive without anything attached. Though it is unusual in every day German because of the dying genitive. One would rather say "der Traumberuf von jedem Kind(e)", though I personally don't like this abuse of dative, but that's just me.

Comment: @tofro: English seems to have similar quirks; *jeder* can be translated "each" or "every", but these aren't interchangeable. For example you can say "To each his own," but not "To everyone his own." And you can say, "Everyone's life is at stake," but not "Each's life is at stake." What I'm surprised about is that the rule does not appear the grammars I usually look at. I did find it mentioned in some texts from the early 19th century though.

Comment: @rnva: Well, why do you think that there is something wrong with the translation and what makes you unsure about your proposal? GoogleTranslate is no argument unless you declare GT an english and german native speaker the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally the translation is "Du hast den Traumberuf jedes Kindes gefunden" (or "Du hast den Traumberuf eines jeden Kindes gefunden" but this one sounds educational or old-fashioned).

You could also say "Du hast den Traumberuf aller Kinder gefunden" (literally "of all kids").

Strictly speaking, "jedes" or "eines jeden" is stronger because it says that every single kid dreams of this job. "Aller" is a general statement about a group and therefore has a tolerance in it. In everyday speech there is no difference between them (I think it is the same with "of every kid" and "of all kids" in English).

Answer (score 1):

"Ein jeder" und "jeder" are synonymous in their meaning, but putting "ein" before "jeder" makes it substantival and puts some emphasis to fact that a condition or circumstance applies to each and every one.

Google translates the phrase to "eines jeden Kindes" and I as a German definitely side with that when it comes to correct grammar. "eines jeden" is simply the genitive of "ein jeder/ein jedes". "jedes Kindes" is grammatically correct, it is the genitive of "jedes Kind", but unusual in every day language.

Colloquially one would say "von jedem Kind" because in current German language the *dative is the genitive's death*.

"... der alle Kinder ..." is wrong sentence building.

Comment: I'm still confused though. I can see that it's correct by the usage examples, but I don't understand *why* it's correct. Is it an idiom? The word for word translation into English is "You've found the dream job of an every child," which is grammatically wrong. If German is different then please explain the difference: is it only the genitive? is it only *jed-* and not *all-*? I've searched several grammars and haven't found anything which allows this construction.

Comment: As I mentioned in another comment, it's the combination of two determiners in a row. It's not allowed in English and I haven't been able to find out when it is allowed in German. You can combine "every" with some nouns in English: "It's the story of a simple everyman." I don't see it as being related to this though.

Comment: @RDBury: See also: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18937/bedeutung-von-eines-jeden-und-vergleich-mit-jedes. In texts from the 19th century you will sometimes find "eines jedes Kindes", schlepping the genitive all the way through. Language evolution has probably introduce an acussative'esque element into "eines jeden". Current German simply uses "ein jeder" synonymously für "jeder".

Comment: I found that question as well, but to me the answer still does not resolve the main issue. I'm sorry if I seem to be persnickety about this, but it looks like I've missed something basic about some very common words and it's disconcerting. I can see using an adjective here: *... jedes einzelnen Kindes gefunden*, but the two determiners still mystify me.

Comment: Oh, one can even say "Eines jeden einzelnen Kindes (Pausenbrot wurde gestohlen)" to put specific emphasis on a condition that applies to each and every single child.

Comment: I'm just re-reading my comments over a year later. So apparently you can just add *ein* to *jeder* with little change in meaning. I'm thinking it's similar to (but not the same as) adding "single" to "every". It's used with the genitive most often, but apparently it can be used with other cases and still be grammatical. Sometimes you just run into these little expressions that don't strictly follow the expected rules of grammar, and sometimes you just have to add an exception to the rules.